# Bind the currently running function to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my JQuery.

My code works like this,

There is a table of names with input boxes at the bottom of the table to add a new name and role, when both of the input boxes are filled in, the code adds the values of the input boxes to a new table row.

My problem is, when the content is added, I want to add another row of input boxes so more people can be added, however... The function that runs when the input boxes have lost focus/blurred is bound to my original input elements and when the next row of inputs is added, I am basically trying to bind the function i'm currently running to the element... Is this possible or how else should I tackle this..

Code:

```
$('.add_new_castcrew').bind("blur",function(){
    castCrewBlur(this);
});

function castCrewBlur(element){

    if(castChangeLength == 2){
        $('#newCast').removeAttr('id');
        console.log("HAHAHAHA");
        $('#cast_table').append("<tr id=\"newCast\"><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"Cast Member Name\" class=\"add_new_castcrew\" id=\"new_cast_name\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"Cast Member Role\" class=\"add_new_castcrew\" id=\"new_cast_role\"></td></tr>");    
        castChangeLength = 0;
        $('#newCast.contentAdded ').each(function(){$(element).removeClass("contentAdded"); console.log("Removed"); });
        $('.add_new_castcrew').bind("click",function(){
            newCastCrewClick(this);
        });    

        $('.add_new_castcrew').bind("click",function(){
            castCrewBlur(this);
        });
```

Comment: Please format your code properly next time. And part of it seems to be missing.

Comment: The code that Is important is there. The rest works fine, it is simply the part where I am binding a blur to the newly appended input box

Comment: The code in your question binds to `click` twice instead of `click` then `blur`. Would this be the problem?

Comment: Your handler code re-binds the handler twice to the same elements so you will get an exponential cascade of triggered functions, growing every time you click…

Comment: Sorry, it worked. I changed the wrong part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "it is simply the part where I am binding a blur to the newly appended
>   input box"

It seems like you're actually binding to the .click()...

```
$('.add_new_castcrew').bind("click",function(){
    castCrewBlur(this);
});
```

Comment: I fixed it doing this actually, sorry, I edited the wrong part.

Comment: great! glad you figured things out